# JpaRepository does not read string parameter in a native query

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

I am facing a problem with my JpaRepository in a spring boot application
I want to perform a simple update query on my database, but it turns out that the native query is quite annoying, please help

```
public interface ImageRepository extends JpaRepository<Image, Integer> {
    @Modifying 
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE image SET path =(0?), status = (1?) WHERE Id = (2?)", nativeQuery = true)
    void update(String path ,String status,int Id);

}
```

the code above returns the following error message

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
```

I have tried to change SQL dialect to
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
respectively and non of them worked.

I tried also to write the query in a different way which does not give me an error but it does not update the fields. it can detect the integer value from the method but it will set the string values to an emply value:

```
    @Query(value = "UPDATE image SET physical_path =(0), status = (1) WHERE Id = (2)", nativeQuery = true)
```

If anyone has faced the same issue please support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame the query like this :

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE image i SET path =:path, status = :status WHERE i.Id = :Id", nativeQuery = true)
void update(@Param("path") String path , @Param("status") String status, @Param("Id") int Id);
```

**For positional parameters :**

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE image i SET path = ?1, status = ?2 WHERE i.Id = ?3", nativeQuery = true)
void update(String path , String status, int Id);
```

Comment: thanks, the first method worked for me. I have tried the second one you suggested, but it did not work for me. anyway thanks, now I can move one with the rest of the code. I was really annoyed by this method for more than two hours

Comment: No problem. Glad to know that you could move forward with your work.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Spring Data JPA - Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) you can see that the parameters (in the way you want to use them) are defined like -> `?1, ?2 etc..`

Also, please keep in mind that the JPQL syntax is slightly different than plain sql.

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Image i set i.path = ?1 where i.status = ?2 where i.id = ?3")
void update(String path, String status, int id);
```

Comment: thanks for the information, but I have tried this query and it did not do the job. the solution, however, is stated by @Som. thanks again for answering

Comment: Hey @Fadi feel free to let me know what was the problem with this answer

Comment: I am getting Incorrect syntax near '@P0'  error. Which indicates that the parameters connot be accessed  from the query. What weird is that I had the same code two month ago and it worked as expected. But after new installation of SQL server 2019 I started to get som issues with JPA repository for some reasons.